# Want to extend a PHP class from two classes one of which is abstract

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

Can I extend a PHP class from two classes, one of which is abstract and other one is not?
like:

```
class customer extends SomeControllerClass implements SomeAbstractClass {
...
}
```

the reason to do is that I have my commonly used functions and logic in the abstract class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. But there are [traits](http://www.php.net/traits) in PHP 5.4 that you can use for that.

Answer (score 4):

Think about this: do you only want inheritance for reusability, or is there an is-a relationship? if it is just the former, then delegation is a better solution.  For the latter you will need to use interfaces and probably delegation again to achieve this.  So the answer is use delegation.